# Top zone affects my right and left zone

Tags: 2013, web-part-zone

I'm using SharePoint 2013 sites as part of a work tool.
I cannot screendump you anything as its covered in confidential material, but I will try and illustrate my issues.

So every site I get come with this default build of zones
width a top zone, left and right that looks like a 66/34 share

[image: Default setup]

**The Issue is**
As soon as I add any webpart to the top zone it changes the relation of the left and right zones

[image: After adding a webpart to top zone]

I don't want this :)

but as far as I can tell nothing I add has fixed width or height.
So why does adding something to top bar change default?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you provide any further details like your page layout code or CSS you are using in page or are you using any custom page layout, people can't help you in an exact manner you have expected.

However, see my page layout code chunk as below. I have added 3 web part zones: header with 100% width, Left zone with 66% and Right zone with 33% width, and its working as expected:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <div class="welcome blank-wp">
        <div class="ms-table ms-fullWidth">
            <div class="">
                <div class="cell-margin" style="width:100%;">
                    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="<%$Resources:cms,WebPartZoneTitle_Header%>" ID="Header"/>
                </div>
                <div class="ms-table ms-fullWidth">
                    <div class="cell-margin" style="width:66%;">
                        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="<%$Resources:cms,WebPartZoneTitle_TopLeft%>" ID="TopLeftRow" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell-margin" style="width:33%;">
                        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="<%$Resources:cms,WebPartZoneTitle_TopRight%>" ID="TopRightRow" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

You can also check if there is any CSS or other design components added in top zone web part affects your page layout structure.